Can the Pythagorean theorem be proved using imaginary numbers?
Can the Pythagorean theorem be proved using imaginary numbers? The proof must avoid circular reasoning, of course.
I asked essentially the same question at MSE, but did not receive a definitive answer, so I thought I would ask here.

Actually I think it's not at all clear how to give any (modern) proof of the Pythagorean theorem that doesn't feel at least a little bit circular in spirit. The issue boils down to the question: where does the Euclidean distance formula come from, if it doesn't come from the Pythagorean theorem? I spent awhile thinking about this off and on and I still don't feel totally satisfied, but I think the most honest answer is that it must and can only come from our phenomenological experience of physical space (e.g. the fact that we can freely rotate our bodies).

@QiaochuYuan What's your view of proving the Pythagorean theorem "synthetically" from Tarski's axioms? This makes no reference to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ as a model for the axioms and so the Euclidean distance formula doesn't enter the picture. Right? Now, you can ask about where Tarski's axioms come from, and I agree that physical intuition plays a role, but at least the apparent circularity associated with the Pythagorean theorem itself has been eliminated.

@TimothyChow I agree. The Pythagorean theorem is a theorem for a good reason. It has a proof (in fact many different proofs) based on the axioms of Euclidean geometry.

Yes. Write a complex number $a+bi$ in polar form $ce^{it}$. Then
$$a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)=(ce^{it})(ce^{-it})=c^2.$$
This is the first theorem I prove in my complex analysis class (after defining complex multiplication via the polar form and checking that it agrees with the more traditional definition via $i^2=-1$ and distributivity).
Added. See the comments for more details what this proof is really based on, and why it is not circular.

According to my understanding, this proof has met with objections, here and here. I believe the gist of the objections is that, in this proof, distance is implicitly being defined using the Pythagroean theorem, thus the reasoning is circular. I'm not sure what to make of the objections.

@Dan No. In my class, I base complex arithmetic on Euclidean geometry where distance is given (it is not a defined quantity but part of the model). It is a genuine proof just as any proof in Euclidean geometry. The difference is that here complex arithmetic is based on Euclidean geometry, and then the Pythagorean theorem becomes a one-liner as in my post. I leave you to fill in the details (or come to my class).

@GHfromMO Do you have class notes on a website, so that we can see that approach fleshed out?

@FedericoPoloni No, unfortunately. At any rate, I take for granted the representations $a+bi$ and $re^{it}$ of complex numbers, where $e^{it}$ abbreviates $\cos t+i\sin t$. These follow from Euclidean geometry. Then I define the sum of complex numbers as $(a+bi)+(a'+b'i):=(a+a')+(b+b')i$, and the product of complex numbers as $(re^{it})(r'e^{it'}):=(rr')e^{i(t+t')}$. So addition comes from translation, while multiplication comes from rotation and dilation. One can check with Euclidean geometry that we obtain a field this way. As $i=e^{i\pi/2}$, we have $i^2=e^{i\pi}=-1$, etc. Nice and easy.

@GHfromMO The context that you have defined complex arithmetic through Euclidean geometry is absolutely essential, and it should not be left in the comments. Please include it in your answer body, because one could interpret your answer as being just like many other identical circular answers that I’ve seen. At any rate, I might still have lingering questions e.g. it seems as if your primitive notion of Euclidean distance is real-valued, and I’d have to think a little more to find others

@EmilJeřábek You did not pay attention to what I wrote. $e^{-it}e^{it}$ is, by the definition of complex multiplication I gave, equal to $e^{i0}=1$. The law of distributivity is deduced from Euclidean geometry: when you rotate and dilate a triangle, you get a triangle. Hence $e^{it}e^{-it}=(\cos t+i\sin t)(\cos t-i\sin t)$ also equals $\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t$. This is a proof of the Pythagorean theorem!

@EmilJeřábek It seems they have defined things so that $e^{it}e^{-it}$ is definitionally $e^{i(t+(-t))}=e^0=1$. Though, to connect the number ‘$c$’ as in polar form with the Euclidean distance seems to have the same content as $|e^{it}|=1$, so I too would like to see this fully fleshed out in a noncircular way. It could be horribly tedious though, as we ought to decide what foundations we are using to even phrase the Pythagorean theorem, and check if these are compatible with $\Bbb C$. In comments under Dan’s post on MSE I describe why I think we shouldn’t even try to prove this in $\Bbb C$

@FShrike It follows from Euclidean geometry that every nonzero complex number has a unique polar decomposition $re^{it}$. Of course $r$ is the length of the number (distance from the origin), while $t$ is the angle of the number (directed angle measured from the positive real axis). Here $e^{it}$ abbreviates the unit vector with angle $t$, which in Cartesian coordinates equals $(\cos t,\sin t)$; this is the definition of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$. At any rate, $re^{it}$ abbreviates $r(\cos t+i\sin t)$, that is, $r\cos t+ir\sin t$. See the "Added" section in my post. I stop here for lack of time.

@FShrike One more thing. The linear algebra version of the above proof would go as follows. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard orthonormal basis. Rotation about the origin by angle $t$ has matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}$, while rotation about the origin by angle $-t$ has matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&\sin t\-\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}$. So the product of these two matrices is the identity matrix. Performing the multiplication of these two matrices, we infer that $\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t=1$, which is the Pythagorean theorem. This is not a circular proof!

Sorry, I missed that multiplication is defined in polar coordinates. So this means the real proof happens in establishing the identity $a^2+b^2=(a+ib)(a-ib)$, i.e., distributivity. I have no idea what to make of "when you rotate and dilate a triangle, you get a triangle".

@EmilJeřábek As we defined multiplication in polar coordinates, it follows that the map $z\mapsto wz$ is a rotation (by the angle of $w$) followed by a dilation (by the length of $w$). Now consider a triangle with side vectors $z_1,z_2,z_1+z_2$. Applying the above mentioned rotation and dilation to this triangle, we get a triangle with side vectors $wz_1,wz_2,w(z_1+z_2)$. Hence $wz_1+wz_2=w(z_1+z_2)$, which is the law of distributivity. Combining this with $i^2=-1$ (which follows from the definition of multiplication), we get that $1=(\cos t+i\sin t)(\cos t-i\sin t)=\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t$.

All right, thank you for the explanation.

Sorry, but what does it mean that distance "is not a defined quantity but part of the model"? I feel this answer is not quite self-contained, even taking the comments into account.

@R.P. My answer is not self-contained as there is a long road from the axioms of Euclidean geometry to this proof. Let me correct myself regarding distance: it is a defined quantity, but the definition is based on congruences rather than the Pythagorean theorem (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms). My position is that one can introduce complex arithmetic in a geometric way (without using the Pythagorean theorem), and this leads to a transparent proof of the Pythagorean theorem. One can also use linear algebra instead of complex arithmetic, as I explained in an earlier remark.

"It follows from Euclidean geometry that every nonzero complex number has a unique polar decomposition $re^it$". No, it has nothing to do with Euclidean geometry. The polar decomposition is the result of none other than $e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$. You just implicitly decided that t means the argument/angle and r is the modulus/length of a + bi. In other words, you redefined length in such a way that it is convenient for you to prove the theorem

Also how do you know that the rotation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}$? What is a rotation ? It seems that you rather prove the theorem by establishing that a less trivial fact is true.

@ioveri Rotation is a notion that you can derive from Euclidean geometry. For every two distinct points $O$ and $P$, there is a unique point $R$ such that the directed angle $ROP$ equals $t$. We call $R$ the rotation of $P$ about $O$. Assuming $O=(0,0)$, rotation by angle $t$ brings $(1,0)$ to $(\cos t,\sin t)$ by the definition of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$. Moreover, it brings $(0,1)$ to $(-\sin t,\cos t)$ by rotating the former point by $\pi/2$. So Euclidean geometry can explain that the matrix of the rotation in question equals $\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}$.

@ioveri To your earlier remark: you (and others here) seem not to follow what I am saying. Perhaps you don't have a good relationship with Euclidean geometry. What I am saying is that starting from the axioms of Euclidean geometry, one can introduce angle and length, rotation and translation, Descartian coordinates, cosine and sine, complex arithmetic etc. Then it is a theorem that every nonzero vector $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ has a unique polar decomposition $(r\cos t,r\sin t)$. In the language of complex arithmetic, every nonzero complex number $a+bi$ can be written uniquely as $r e^{it}$, etc

No, I completely understand what you said. The problem is that, as I said, you are proving it by redefining terms in a way that's more convenient to prove the theorem, at the cost of accepting i.e. axiomatizing things that are far less intuitive than the theorem itself. It's basically "I can prove the theorem, but you have to believe that rotation is a linear transformation, where $(0,1)$ is mapped to $(\cos t, \sin t)$ and $(1,0)$ is mapped to $(-\sin t, \cos t)$ and $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are defined by ..."

It is a pointless proof IMO, because you use tools whose historical development relies on the Pythagorean theorem itself, but you simply accept them as axioms so that circularity can be avoided.

@ioveri It is not pointless to rethink mathematics, e.g. what is the "best way" to introduce complex arithmetic or prove the Pythagorean theorem. The latter can be deduced from the axioms of Euclidean geometry in many ways. My position is that it is natural to introduce complex arithmetic first, and then deduce the Pythagorean theorem with the help of it. Similarly, the addition theorems of cosine and sine admit natural proofs via complex arithmetic which can be summed up as $e^{i(t+t')}=e^{it}e^{it'}$. Equivalently, if $R(t)$ is the rotation matrix discussed above, then $R(t+t')=R(t)R(t')$.

@ioveri And to your previous remark: no, you don't have to believe that rotations are linear transformations. You can regard this fact as a theorem in Euclidean geometry: if you rotate a paralelogram, you get a paralelogram, etc. Also, you don't have to believe that $(1,0)$ goes to $(\cos t ,\sin t)$ under the rotation. Instead, we call $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ the coordinates of the rotated point, and then you observe (again using Euclidean geometry) that $(0,1)$ gets rotated to $(-\sin t,\cos t)$.

@ioveri One more thing. The original (historic) definitions of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are much like the definition I am using above: coordinates of the point on the unit circle corresponding to $t$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry

If you define $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ in that way then it will not neccessarily be related to commonly known $e^{it}$ anymore. The historical $\sin t$ treats $t$ as a seperate object with unit e.g. degree, gradian, rad. The modern $\sin t$ treats $t$ as a number because it is the arc length/radius ratio, or the arc length for the unit circle. You will have to introduce $\pi$ as a scaling constant to make those definitions equal.

This may sound pedantic but I think it's better to use  alternative notation is better like $c\angle t \cdot c \angle(-t)$

@ioveri I finish this discussion here because: (1) MathOverflow is not a chat site, (2) I don't have time for this. It is fine with me if you think that the above proof of the Pythagorean theorem is incomplete/circular/pointless.
